# Error al enviar el formulario presionado la tecla enter

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Buenos días a toda la comunidad. mi problema es el siguiente. estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación y el cliente me pide que el formulario que los productos se van a facturar se agreguen presionando la tecla enter. investigando en internet conseguí esta forma de enviar el formulario presionando la TECLA ENTER pero el problema que tengo es que cuando se envía presionando dicha tecla se agregan muchas veces el mismo registro cosa que no pasa cuando se hace agregan dando click con el mouse. lo que quiero es que cuando se presione la tecla ENTER se envié solo una vez.

Esta es la función que se encarga de agregar los productos a facturar

```
var agregarAFacturacion=function(tbody,table){
$(tbody).on('click', 'button.agregar', function() {
  var data = table.row( $(this).parents("tr")).data();
  //console.log(data);
  //var cantidad=1;
  $('#nom_producto').text(data.nombre_producto);
  $('#descripcion_producto').val(data.nombre_producto);
  $('#precio_producto').val(data.p);
  $('#id_producto').val(data.codigo);
  $('#precio4').val(data.p4);
  $('#modalAgregarPro').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

      $('#cantidad_producto').focus();

      $("#form_agregar_editar").keyup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
           if(e.which == 13) {
              // Dar Click para enviar el formulario.
              $("#agregarProducto").click();
           }
        });
      
     
    })
  

});
```

}

Este es el modal donde esta el formulario

```
<!-- Modal AGREGAR / MODIFICAR PRODUCTO-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregarPro" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="nom_producto"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="form_agregar_editar">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Descripcion: </strong></label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
             <!--  codigo del producto -->
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_producto" hidden="">
              <!-- precio anterior del producto para saber cual debe actualizar -->
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio_anterior" hidden="">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion_producto">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio4" hidden="">
             
              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Cantidad:</strong></label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
            
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad_producto" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Precio:</strong></label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio_producto">
            </div>
          </div>
        
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="agregarProducto">Agregar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" hidden="" id="confirmar_editar_producto" data-dismiss="modal">Editar</button>
        
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

espero puedan ayudarme o en caso mostrarme como hacer para solo se envié el formulario una sola vez. muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿De que versión de bootstrap se trata?

Comment: bootstrap 4....

Comment: Pues ciérrale el modal y si no es suficiente prueba con `$(tbody).off('click','button.agregar')` despues de ejecutar el `$("#agregarProducto").click();` o desde dentro de el

Comment: No te faltará usar el.preventDefault(); y e.stopPropagation();

Comment: Voy a intentar lo que me recomiendan muchas gracias ya les digo si funciona o no jejejee.

Comment: EL stopPropagation() era lo que me faltaba agregarle ya me funciona correctamente. muchas gracias por su apoyo.